# How to resize media images in magento?

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento

I am using magento 1.7 version.I have some images with product.Now I want to show as a slider in detail page.my code is below:-

```
<?php if (count($_product->getMediaGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>  
<div class="more-views">

<div class="productsmallImage">
    <div id="slider2">
        <a class="buttons prev" href="javascript:;">left</a>
        <div class="viewport">                 
            <ul class="overview">            
                <?php foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image):?>
                <li>
                    <!--No lightbox on click of image-->
                  <a href="<?php echo $_image->getUrl();?>" title="<?php echo $_image->getName();?>" onclick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;">
                      <img src="<?php echo $_image->getUrl(); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="buttons next" href="javascript:;">right</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this count($_product->getMediaGalleryImages()) has value 4.All the images showing but need to resize them.Please help to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the following construction for images output:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
```

> Fixed width of 600px

```
$image_Url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')
 ->init($_product, 'image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(600,null)
?>
```

> **Fixed height of 600px**

```
$image_Url =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')
              ->init($_product, 'image')
               ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
               ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
               ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                ->resize(null,600)
```

> **The following code will resize image proportionally and not let
>   the image be greater than height and width specified.**

```
 $_image_Url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')
                          ->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())
                          ->keepFrame(true)
                          ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                          ->constrainOnly(true)
                          ->resize(600,600);


<img src="<?php echo  $_imageUrl; ?>" alt="" class="normal"/>


}
```